# How to put labels on a plotted graph?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[->] (-3.5,0) -- (3.5,0) node[right] {$x$};
  \draw[->] (0,-3.5) -- (0,3.5) node[above] {$y$};
  \draw[scale=1,domain=-2:2,smooth,variable=\x,blue] plot ({\x},{\x*\x - 1});
  \draw[scale=1,domain=-2:2,smooth,variable=\y,red]  plot ({\y},{\y});
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I would like to number the x and y axes with the usual integer values. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to complete axis with tick defined with `foreach` loop:

```
%\documentclass{amsart}
%\usepackage{tikz}
\documentclass[tikz,margin=10pt]{standalone}
%\usepackage{pst-plot}
%\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
%\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}
```

[image]

Other way is to draw diagram with `pgfplots` where the ticks are defined with option of used axis:

```
    %\documentclass{amsart}
%\usepackage{tikz}
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
%\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xlabel={$x$},
                 ylabel={$y$},
                 axis lines=center,
                 xmin=-3.5, xmax=3.5,
                 ymin=-3, ymax=3
                 ]
    \addplot[domain=-2:2,smooth,variable=\x,red] {\x*\x - 1};
    \addplot[domain=-2:2,smooth,variable=\y,blue] {\y};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]